# Pushing Category and Publish Date to Google Analytics

Tags: variables

I have found an interesting [article](http://cutroni.com/blog/2012/09/12/google-analytics-custom-variables-for-publishers/) about tracking variables with JS based statical system (for example Google Analytics).

The article writes examples like:

```
_gaq.push('setCustomVar', 3, 'pubDate','YYYYMM',3);
_gaq.push('setCustomVar', 4, 'contCat','[CATEGORY NAME]',3);
_gaq.push('setCustomVar', 5, 'contSubCat','[SUB CATEGORY NAME]',3);
```

But how can I get the actual value of the pubdate from the PHP environment of Wordpress and write it in the HTML generated code so that it will be really made available to analytics? I hope the question is clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're printing your script inline (i.e. not in an external file), you can use PHP to dynamically output the JavaScript argument:

```
<script>
    _gaq.push( 'setCustomVar', 3, 'pubDate', '<?php the_time( 'Ym' ) ?>', 3 );
</script>
```

See the [PHP manual for date arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), which will explain why I've used `Ym`.

Comment: the_time is the WP function for getting when it was published? very nice.. If you don't mind to modify your answer I will edit the question to ask also for the category so that it will become even more useful

Comment: It's possible to have multiple categories per post, so you'd need to decide how to handle that, e.g. only display one. [get_the_category()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category) gives you all the details – id, name, slug, parent etc. – in an array, so you can extract the information you need.